# About spring loaded solderless connector for JTAG pads

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, connector, jtag

The [14-pin JTAG header](http://s24.postimg.org/4zvo7xmqd/JTAG.jpg) on a PCB, JTAG pads without holes, no other holes on PCB around JTAG connection area. Does it exist a special solderless JTAG connector for connecting JTAG cable to such JTAG header, by connecting spring loaded [Pogo Pins](http://s27.postimg.org/99y8tqc03/G18226_B.jpg) to the top of the JTAG pads and fixing them in this position for reliable contact? The main problem is to fix Pogo pins vertically on JTAG pads on PCBs.

[image]

Comment: Do you need a one-off solution, or your intent is to test billions of these?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't holes hiding under the solder?

Comment: There are no holes under JTAG pads in the bottom side of the PCB, and I don't want to drill holes and spoil board.

Comment: It's still better to leave holes and use chisel-tip pogo pins.  Self-centering.

Comment: well, the better is solution which is suitable for the actual situation, rather than the theoretical.

Comment: there are some interesting items for sale on ebay - try searching for "jtag spring loaded"

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely.  [TAG-CONNECT](http://www.tag-connect.com/JLINK) specializes in connectors of these sorts for a variety of different platforms.  That approach uses alignment holes with thru pins to keep these things lined up.  They make them with and without "feet" that clip them to the board for a no-hands approach, and they offer a retaining clip to help you hold it on for debugging when you don't have the real estate for holes.

They recommend that you adjust solder stencils so as to not put any solder paste on these pogo-pin targets.

[image]
From http://www.tag-connect.com/sites/default/files/images/ddblock/1tag.jpg

Comment: Not sure that they have connector for standard **14-pin JTAG header**, and there is _no alignment pin holes_ on PCB around JTAG, how then this connector can be fixed on PCB? This PCB is not designed specifically for Tag-Connect.

Comment: Ahhh, now I understand.  I have a feeling that the connector you see is designed to work with pogo pins when the whole shebang is placed in a test fixture w/ some sort of bed of nails tester. Without alignment pins, that really is one of your only options.

Comment: It could be two clamps mounted on the edges of PCB and which press pogo pins to the JTAG pads. (sort of clamp)